# Average values of a MAT channel

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I want to obtain the average values of a MAT and MatND variable, just to estimate the sharpness and brightness. However, I have been facing real issues with the vague values I have been encountering. I tried my best, but am still confused. I really do not know, if am doing the right thing.

```
    calcHist(&src_yuv,1,channels,Mat(),hist,1,histSize,ranges,true,false);
    Size d = hist.size();
    rows = d.height;
    cols = d.width;
    for(int k=0;k<hbins;k++)
    {
     for(int l=0;l<sbins;l++)
     {
       total = total + hist.at<float>(k,l);
     }
    }
    brightness = total/(rows*cols);
```

Here , am trying to calculate the histogram of the luma channel of src_yuv, which is in YUV format and average the values. Am I doing it the right way? If I change the datatype within <' '>, ranging from uchar to long int, am ending up with different values, which is understandable. But I dunno which is the right data type to use. Moreover, should I loop it within hbins,sbins or rows, cols? Please help me. am stuck at this for a long time.

```
     Laplacian(src_gray,dst,ddepth,kernel_size,scale,delta,BORDER_DEFAULT);
     Size s = dst.size();
     rows = s.height;
     cols = s.width;
     total = 0;
     max =  0;
     for(int k=0;k<rows;k++)
     {
       for(int l=0;l<cols;l++)
       {
          total = total + dst.at<>(k,l);
       }
     }
     average = total/(rows*cols);
```

What is the exact way to compute average in the above case? Could you please help me here? I tried different datatypes, starting from in for the mat, and long int for the total and averages. Its a gray scale image, and the result in the laplacian convoluted image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the input src_yuv to BGR before calcHist and you will get the desired output with the same code.

EDIT: for YUV:-

```
out = imread("Lena.jpg");
out.convertTo(out, CV_RGB2YCrCb);
MatND hist;
int hbins = 30, sbins = 32;
int histSize[] = {hbins, sbins};
float hranges[] = { 0, 180 };
float sranges[] = { 0, 256 };
 int channels[] = {0,1,2};
const float* ranges[] = { hranges, sranges };
calcHist( &out, 1, channels, Mat(), 
         hist, 2, histSize, ranges,
         true, 
         false );
Size d = hist.size();
int rows = d.height;
int cols = d.width;
float total;
float brightness;
for(int k=0;k<hbins;k++)
{
    for(int l=0;l<sbins;l++)
    {
        total = total + hist.at<float>(k,l);
    }
}
brightness = total/(rows*cols);
```

this gives me brightness to be 246.895

Comment: My sole purpose is to use YUV, to compute brightness. Could you please tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Am not sure if wat am saying is correct, but by using all the 3 channels, will I get the exact estimate of brightness? I have been trying to use the Luma ('Y') channel alone. could you please tell me , if, by using channel = {0}, am I using the luma channel?

Comment: from the answer on one of your other questions, I quote: "if you start with an image in BGR and convert using BGR2YUV, then you trust that the Y channel is the first one, and so on. If OpenCV ever changes BGR2YUV to mean that Y goes to the last channel, and so on, then too bad for you." Look what I did. The conversion is from BGR to YUV and thus you will get the Y channel only when doing channel = {0}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience, I was ble to understand this channel and conversion issues. My final confusion, is regarding the average. Could you please help me there? Am still trying different methods. Could you please check the edit?

Comment: mean(InputArray src, InputArray mask=noArray()) will give you the average for a Mat src